# Swig java.nio.file.Path <--> boost::filesystem::path

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I am new to swig and have read through the documentation but am still struggling.

In my library header I have the following class:

```
class Facade
{
public:
  static bool Init(const boost::filesystem::path &path);
};
```

I am trying to get it so that users can pass a `java.nio.file.Path` from the java code through the JNI layer created by swig. Here is my swig definition file:

```
%module FacadeInterface
%{
#include "Facade.h"
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
%}
%pragma(java) jniclassimports=%{
import java.nio.file.Path;
%}
%pragma(java) moduleimports=%{
import java.nio.file.Path;
%}
%typemap(jstype) boost::filesystem::path & "java.nio.file.Path"
%typemap(jstype) boost::filesystem::path "java.nio.file.Path"
%typemap(jtype) boost::filesystem::path & "java.nio.file.Path"
%typemap(jtype) boost::filesystem::path "java.nio.file.Path"
%typemap(jni) boost::filesystem::path & "jobject"
%typemap(jni) boost::filesystem::path "jobject"
%typemap(in) boost::filesystem::path {...}
%typemap(in) boost::filesystem::path & {...}
%typemap(out) boost::filesystem::path {...}
%typemap(out) boost::filesystem::path & {...}
%include "Facade.h"
```

This only partially works in that the java code builds an interface that takes a `java.nio.file.Path` but then tries to convert it to a `SWIGTYPE_p_boost__filesystem__path`. For example generated code appears as.

```
public class Facade {
    ...
    public static boolean Init(java.nio.file.Path path) {
        return FacadeInterfaceJNI.Facade_Init(
            SWIGTYPE_p_boost__filesystem__path.getCPtr(path));
    }
    ...
  }
```

What do I need to do to get the `java.nio.file.Path` convertible to a `boost::filesystem::path`.

My java compiler errors are as follows:

```
/root/build/src/main/com/Facade.java:39: error: incompatible types: Path cannot be converted to SWIGTYPE_p_boost__filesystem__path
    return FacadeInterfaceJNI.Facade_Init(SWIGTYPE_p_boost__filesystem__path.getCPtr(modelPath));
```

Comment: Isn't `java.io.File` a better match for a `boost::filesystem::path`?

Comment: @Flexo probably is. Not sold on either one. I know you can use the ctor to contruct a File but not a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the typemaps weren't getting applied because of a mismatch on 'constness'. (Your function takes `const boost::filesystem::path &path`, but your typemaps are for `boost::filesystem::path &`, so can't be applied).

I think the simplest way to make this work is to pass the path as a string across the language boundaries. You can do that with the following typemaps, which on the Java side call `toString()` on the path, and on the C++ side pass that into a constructor for the boost path object:

```
%module test

%{
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <iostream>
%}

%typemap(jni) const boost::filesystem::path& "jstring"
%typemap(jstype) const boost::filesystem::path& "java.nio.file.Path"
%typemap(jtype) const boost::filesystem::path& "String"
%typemap(javain) const boost::filesystem::path& "$javainput.toString()"
%typemap(in) const boost::filesystem::path& (boost::filesystem::path tmp) {
    const char *str = JCALL2(GetStringUTFChars, jenv, $input, 0);
    tmp = str;
    $1 = &tmp;
    JCALL2(ReleaseStringUTFChars, jenv, $input, str);
}

%inline %{
    void test(const boost::filesystem::path& p) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
%}
```

Doing it like this saves more JNI calls inside the `in` typemap, which would inevitably have ended up calling several functions to get a string representation in the end anyway.

(This compiles, but I've not run it).

Comment: I can run with the example and view the output to see what impacts what. Your insight is extremely useful. If I could upvote it more I would.